the open() function not being recognized
My code involves file operations using open() and related functions. But I am encountering an "identifier not found" error for open(), even though I have included the required header (<fcntl.h>).
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Relevant code using open() function
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    // Further operations involving file descriptors

    close(fd); // Closing the file descriptor
    return 0;
}

From my understanding, open() is a standard function for file operations in UNIX-like systems, but it seems the compiler can't locate it. Could you help clarify why this error might be occurring, and how to resolve it?

Seems in io.h for me, and you need to say #pragma warning(disable : 4996). ("The name is deprecated because it doesn't follow the Standard C rules for implementation-specific names.")

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=msvc-170 you're not using a UNIX like system, you're on windows so need to look at Microsoft's documentation

@AlanBirtles I looked at that page and did not see the io.h requirement. (Sometimes I'm blind though.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica see "Requirements" at the bottom (fairly standard for Microsoft docs)

@AlanBirtles Ah, the headers are at the bottom. Makes complete sense, even more so as a general rule ;-).

Thanks, I followed the advice to include #pragma warning(disable : 4996) as suggested, and it resolved the issue with the deprecated functions in <io.h>. It helped me successfully compile and run my code without encountering the warning. I'm grateful for the assistance!

Any reason you are not using an ifstream derivative?  See std::ifstream::open().

If you must use functions not in standard c++ language, you should check out MSDN: Creating and Opening Files

Even though it appears to be one of the most basic and ubiquitous C functions, open() is "implementation specific": It is a POSIX function. Now POSIX is an attempt to be "portable", but mostly between various Unix flavors. Not every operating system programmable in C has native integer "file descriptors"; those are a *nix concept.
Other operating systems, including early versions of Windows NT (and, as we can see, modern Windows) sometimes provide some varying degree of support for POSIX functions. The reason is surely to help port at least such programs that only use basic, easy-to-implement POSIX functionality from *nixes to those target systems.
The truly portable way to perform I/O is through the C (and additionally, for C++ programs, the C++) standard library (fopen(), ifstream()). The FILE structure on which the C standard library operates is "opaque": The functions return and receive pointers (or, in C++, references) so that the user can ignore their inner makeup.
Now why does Microsoft deprecate open() and replaces it with _open()?
The C++ standard mandates in 5.10, "Identifiers":

Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

I don't read this as making implementation-defined identifiers that do not begin with an underscore non-conformant; but users may rightly be surprised by collisions of such names with names introduced by the implementation. Consequently, Microsoft changed the name to _open(), a name which is reserved for implementations. The old name triggers warning C4996, which appears to have been turned into an error — to avoid it, one has to add #pragma warning(disable : 4996).
Finally, the documentation for _open() contains, as Alan Birtles pointed out correctly, the necessary header io.h in the section Requirements.

Windows and Visual C++ has their own version of open/close that requires a leading underscore.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Relevant code using open() function
    int fd = _open("file.txt", _O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    // Further operations involving file descriptors

    _close(fd); // Closing the file descriptor
    return 0;
}

Or even better. Drop the _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS define and  use this to open the file:
auto err = _sopen_s(&fd, "d:/save2.txt", _O_RDONLY, _SH_DENYWR, 0);
if (err != 0) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
}

